# Change order of a DatePicker columns

Tags: android, kotlin, datepicker

The problem is that DatePicker spinner changes the order of its columns(dd, mm, yy) depending of locale. I want to freeze one order for any locales.

I tried

```
binding.datePicker.resources.configuration.setLocale(Locale.US)
```

and changing default locale. It didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, the DateTime spinner is based on the system locale. If you're looking to maintain a constant column spinner, I suggest using a NumberPicker and configuring the picker settings manually.

Create a custom layout for the DatePicker dialog. You'll use three NumberPicker widgets for day, month, and year.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/dayPicker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"/>

    <NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/monthPicker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"/>

    <NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/yearPicker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

In your activity or fragment, you can create a custom DatePickerDialog by inflating the custom layout and setting up the NumberPicker widgets.

```
 public class CustomDatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {

    private NumberPicker dayPicker;
    private NumberPicker monthPicker;
    private NumberPicker yearPicker;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(requireContext());
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_date_picker);

        dayPicker = dialog.findViewById(R.id.dayPicker);
        monthPicker = dialog.findViewById(R.id.monthPicker);
        yearPicker = dialog.findViewById(R.id.yearPicker);

        setupPickerValues(); // Call this method to set up initial values
        setupPickerListeners(); // Call this method to set up listeners

        return dialog;
    }

    private void setupPickerValues() {
        // Set up the NumberPickers as needed
        dayPicker.setMinValue(1);
        dayPicker.setMaxValue(31);
        dayPicker.setValue(25);

        monthPicker.setMinValue(1);
        monthPicker.setMaxValue(12);
        monthPicker.setValue(8);

        yearPicker.setMinValue(1900);
        yearPicker.setMaxValue(2100);
        yearPicker.setValue(2023);
    }

    private void setupPickerListeners() {
        monthPicker.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
                // Handle dynamic day value for February (Feb)
                int selectedYear = yearPicker.getValue();
                int selectedMonth = newVal;
                int maxDay = getMaxDayOfMonth(selectedYear, selectedMonth);
                dayPicker.setMaxValue(maxDay);
            }
        });

        // Set initial max day value based on the current month
        int initialYear = yearPicker.getValue();
        int initialMonth = monthPicker.getValue();
        int initialMaxDay = getMaxDayOfMonth(initialYear, initialMonth);
        dayPicker.setMaxValue(initialMaxDay);
    }

    private int getMaxDayOfMonth(int year, int month) {
        if (month == 2) {
            if ((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0)) {
                return 29; // Leap year
            } else {
                return 28; // Non-leap year
            }
        } else if (month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11) {
            return 30;
        } else {
            return 31;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It would be better to expand setupPickerListeners() with yearPicker.setOnValueChangedListener(...) like that:         ```yearPicker!!.setOnValueChangedListener { picker, oldVal, newVal ->
            val selectedMonth = monthPicker!!.value
            val maxDay = getMaxDayOfMonth(newVal, selectedMonth)
            dayPicker!!.maxValue = maxDay
        }```